# NullPointerException при добавлении ToolBar

Tags: android

MainActivity

```
Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

main.xml

```
 <include layout="@layout/main_toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/main_tb" />
```

main_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#404447">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Советы"
        android:id="@+id/tb_textView"
        android:textColor="#0079FF" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tb_imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_advice"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tb_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tb_textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tb_textView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tb_imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_setting"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tb_textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tb_textView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

При запуске получаю `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` в коде `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`, сразу скажу что ToolBarom пользуюсь 2 раз.  все работало до того как добавил в include ТЕГ ID, это нужно было чтобы выровнить в ReleativeLayout. но в итоге получил Exception...

Comment: Я как понимаю в include нельзя тег ID добавлять чтоли? обернуть его в `ReleativeLayout`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указывая ID у тега `inclide` вы переопределяете ID у вашего элемента `Toolbar`.

Т.е. должно быть

```
Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_tb);
```

В `include` можно переопределить ID и все атрибуты `layout_*` добавляемого элемента. Чтобы переопределить `layout_*`, в include нужно обязательно указать `layout_width` и `layout_height`